# Back-off restarting failed container openshift kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I have a Dockerfile running Kong-api to deploy on openshift. It build okay, but when I check pods I get `Back-off restarting failed container`. Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl lsb-core
RUN echo "deb https://kong.bintray.com/kong-deb `lsb_release -sc` main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN curl -o bintray.key https://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=bintray
RUN apt-key add bintray.key
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y kong

COPY kong.conf /etc/kong/
RUN kong migrations bootstrap [-c /etc/kong/kong.conf]

EXPOSE 8000 8443 8001 8444
ENTRYPOINT ["kong", "start", "[-c /etc/kong/kong.conf]"]
```

Where is my wrong? Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share `kong.conf` to debug at my end.

Comment: @Here_2_learn `kong.conf` is correct. I can running in my local but can't deploy

Comment: What user is this container running as?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the kong start correctly, you need to execute these commands when you have an active Postgres connection:

```
kong migrations bootstrap && kong migrations up
```

Also, note that the format of the current Dockerfile is not valid if you would like
to pass options within the `ENTRYPOINT` you can write it like that:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["kong", "start","-c", "/etc/kong/kong.conf"]
```

Also, you need to remove this line:

```
RUN kong migrations bootstrap [-c /etc/kong/kong.conf]
```

Note that the format of the above line is not valid as `RUN` expects a normal shell command so using `[]` in this case is not correct.

So as you deploy to Openshift there are several ways to achieve what you need.

- You can make use of [initContainers](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/nodes/containers/nodes-containers-init.html) which allows you to execute the required commands before the actual service is up.
- You can check [the official helm chart for Kong](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/kong) in order to know how it works or use helm to install Kong itself.